# ERROR: Permission to project/repo.git denied to deploy key

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to set one repository from GitHub Enterprise in Jenkins as a default pull source. In our project, Jenkins is used to auto-build the whole code base whenever we are pushing some changes. Before we were using Locally installed GIT at our project space. Now we are migrating to GHE.

Change I have made at `Configure` > `Source Code Management tab` > `Repository URL` > `git@github.com:project/repo`.

After a forceful `Build Now` we were getting log error:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:project/repo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:ZjDIk3kbdyojRjqiBBfXS6xOHF+y+9bzcbZypukADHA.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in <jenkins_home>/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in <jenkins_home>/.ssh/known_hosts:49
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
X11 forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
ERROR: Permission to project/repo.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do not have any read/write access at our Jenkins and have requested our Jenkins admin to remove Line 49 at `<jenkins_home>/.ssh/known_hosts` as per the error.

He had done so and he also had shared us `id_rsa.pub` and `id_ecdsa.pub`.
Tried to add these keys as a Deploy key on project/repo.

- For `id_rsa.pub` I got a `Key is already in use` message.
- But `id_ecdsa.pub` got added successfully as deploy key.

But still I am getting an error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.com:project/repo HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ERROR: Permission to project/repo.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also tried `Webhooks` by storing the repository specific path of Jenkins server at GHE, but found no changes:

`https://<jenkins_server>:8080/job/<repo_name>/`

Suggestion/help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are using multiple keys. 
SSH will load the default key unless told otherwise.

#### Create a SSH config file

> When you have multiple identity files, create a SSH config file mechanisms to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName <domain.com>
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host host1
HostName <domain1>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Host host2
HostName <domain2>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

In your case the domain should be the same and add your 2 keys : `id_rsa` , `id_ecdsa`

Comment: I do not have any access at `<jenkins_home>/.ssh/config`. Are you talking about my local `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: It should be on the machine where your 2 keys are.

Answer (score 0):

Edit ssh config:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

Set IdentitiesOnly=no

```
Host *
        IdentitiesOnly=no
```

(thanks to [CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard))